# Save PHP Post Data to string

Tags: php

I have simple PHP Code.
I can echo `$_POST["email"];` correctly.

But I can't save it to variable.

```
var email=$_POST["email"];
```

I got this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR
```

Any idea?

Comment: You trying to use this with JS? Show full code and how you're using this.

Comment: Yeah. What variable is that? Javascript or PHP? Fred is right, please provide us at least your partial code.

Comment: it's in php. And the solution is just use $email=$_POST["email"]; Btw, any idea how to check whether $_POST["email"] has value or not?

Comment: ...use `isset()` and/or `empty()` set in a conditional statement.

Comment: However, using this the way you are now, are opening yourself to XSS injection. Use [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [PHP Variable basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) . You need to change:

```
var email=$_POST["email"];
```

to

```
$email=$_POST["email"];
```

If you want to assign php value to a javascript variable, this would do:

```
var email= '<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>';
```

Comment: Ok, sounds good. But, why? Maybe OP's using this with JS; we can't say for sure. But, you stand at being 50% right.

Comment: hmm.. alright, i think i'll provide a solution for javascript.

Comment: I would've waited to ask OP questions first, as I have. I don't want you to get burned ;)

Comment: thanks. I forget that I need to use $ for variable in php. Mixed with js.

Comment: Paid off; I knew (had a feeling) JS had something to do with it. +1 cheers